# REST services/ Web site Security - Stop page 'flashing' up

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, cookies, nginx

I have a HTML/JS front end (on nginx) and Java EE backend (on Java EE app server) webservice that exposes various REST interfaces. At each interface I check for a valid cookie, if a cookie does not exist I redirect to login page. The 'chink' in this armour is that if a user browses to a page that is protected by a cookie like I described, the page usually 'flashes' up for a split second before the user is redirecetd to log in page.

How can I prevent this page 'flashing' up? Is there something I can do on the webserver perhaps?

**Note**: Changing from using cookies to protect the REST services is not an option at present!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you page is loading *and then* you check for a cookie, then you should expect to see that flashing of the page.

You need to make a call to validate that they can see the page before any of the template is rendered.

if you are using any server side code at all to render templates, you'd do it there.

if you use only client side templating and javascript to render your views, then you need to write javascript functionality that will validate that the user can view the page BEFORE the views/templates are rendered.